# How to get larger text font inside \confpin....ticketpackage

Tags: fonts

This is my Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

\usepackage[freepin,crossmark]{ticket}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{}

\newcommand{\confpin}[1]{\ticket{%
    \put(35,25){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries{\fontsize{1cm}{0pt}\selectfont #1}}}}}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
   \confpin{word}{} %1
   \confpin{word}{} %2
   \confpin{word}{} %3
   \confpin{word}{} %4
   \confpin{word}{} %5
   \confpin{word}{} %6
   \confpin{word}{} %7
   \confpin{word}{} %8
   \confpin{word}{} %9
   \confpin{word}{} %10
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I need my Words to be bigger but can't seem to make it happen.

I have changed the fontsize from small, to smaller, ... to bigger !
But there seem to be a limitation in the height or something, because it only reach a certain size, then stop getting bigger!

```
\newcommand{\confpin}[1]{\ticket{%
    \put(35,25){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries{\fontsize{1cm}{0pt}\selectfont #1}}}}}
```

so if I put 3cm, it as no more effect!!

```
\newcommand{\confpin}[1]{\ticket{%
    \put(35,25){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries{\fontsize{3cm}{0pt}\selectfont #1}}}}}
```

[image]

Can you tell me why ?

Can we go around this and make text as big as possible (and all the  inBetween) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For historical reasons the default cm fonts (only) are restricted to a fixed set of sizes, even though the fonts themselves are scalable, the `fix-cm` package removes this restriction.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

\usepackage[freepin,crossmark]{ticket}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{}

\newcommand{\confpin}[1]{\ticket{%
    \put(35,25){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries{\fontsize{3cm}{0pt}\selectfont #1}}}}}


\begin{document}
\sffamily
   \confpin{word}{} %1
   \confpin{word}{} %2
   \confpin{word}{} %3
   \confpin{word}{} %4
   \confpin{word}{} %5
   \confpin{word}{} %6
   \confpin{word}{} %7
   \confpin{word}{} %8
   \confpin{word}{} %9
   \confpin{word}{} %10
\end{document}
```

Comment: Super Awesome, thank you sir @David